# Kotlin: Initialize class attribute in constructor

Tags: constructor, kotlin, class-attribute

I create a Kotlin-class with a class attribute, which I want to initialize in the constructor:

```
public class TestClass {

    private var context : Context? = null // Nullable attribute

    public constructor(context : Context) {
       this.context = context
    }

    public fun doSomeVoodoo() {
       val text : String = context!!.getString(R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I have to declare the attribute as Nullable with the "?" sign, although the attribute will be initialized in the constructor. Declaring this attribute as Nullable-attribute makes it always necessary to force an NonNull-value with "!!" or to provide a Null-check with "?".

Is there any way to avoid this, if the class attribute will be initialized in the constructor? I would like to appreciate a solution like this one:

```
public class TestClass {

    private var context : Context // Non-Nullable attribute

    public constructor(context : Context) {
       this.context = context
    }

    public fun doSomeVoodoo() {
       val text : String = context.getString(R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description)
    }
}
```

Comment: The second example is working with Kotlin 0.12.213. What Kotlin-Version are you using?

Comment: It works. I already used 0.12.613. But I think, I was doing something wrong. Sorry!

Comment: There are more cases available, I added an answer for complete coverage.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the only thing you are doing in the constructor is an assignment,
then you could use the Primary Constructor with a private Property.

e.g:

```
public class TestClass(private val context: Context) {

  public fun doSomeVoodoo() {
     val text = context.getString(R.string.abc_...)
  }
}
```

Comment: @DamonYuan What would you suggest?

Comment: @D3xter I think it is easy to lead to memory leak.

Answer (score 24):

As shown by D3xter you have the option of setting it in the constructor.  You also have other options.  Here they all are...

Create the property within the constructor (as per @D3xter), *this is the most common case for simple properties initialized directly by the primary constructor*:

```
class TestClass(private val context: Context) {
    fun doSomeVoodoo() {
        val text : String = context.getString()
    } 
}
```

You can declare the `val` property and not initialize it, assuming all possible constructors do actually initialize it (as per your second example in the question being asked).  *This is normal when you have more than one constructor that could initialize a value differently*:

```
public class TestClass {
    private val context: Context

    public constructor(context : Context) {
        this.context = context
    }

    // alternative constructor
    public constructor(pre: PreContext) {
        this.context = pre.readContext()
    }

    public fun doSomeVoodoo() {
        val text : String = context.getString()
    }
}
```

You can pass in constructor parameters that are not property declarations, and then use those within property initializations.  *This is common when you have more complex initializations or need to use delegated properties*:

```
class TestClass(context: PreContext) {
    private val context : Context by lazy { context.readContext() }
    private val other: List<Items> = run {
        context.items.map { it.tag }.filterNotNull()
    }
    private val simpleThing = context.getSimple()

    fun doSomeVoodoo() {
        val text : String = context.getString()
    }
}
```

Using [`lateinit` modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) when you cannot initialize the value during construction, but you are sure it will be done before your first read access.  *This is common when a dependency injection, IoC container, or something creates an empty version of your class and then initializes it immediately*:

```
class TestClass() {
    private lateinit var context : Context // set by something else after construction

    fun doSomeVoodoo() {
        val text : String = context.getString()
    }
}
```

For `lateinit` the property must currently be a `var` and does not work with primitive types.

You can also declare a `var` property and not initialize it if you use a delegate designed for that purpose, such as `Delegates.notNull()`.  *This is similar to `lateinit` and common when you want a `var` that has no initial state, but is set later after construction at unknown point in time*:

```
public class TestClass() {
    private var context: Context by Delegates.notNull()

    public fun doSomeVoodoo() {
        // if context is not set before this is called, an exception is thrown
        val text : String = context.getString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where I didn't want to hold onto the object after construction. Using `lazy` or `lateinit` resulted in inefficient bytecode so after some research I settled on this approach and returned to post the answer in case it helps:

### Solution

```
class TestClass(context: Context) {
    private val homeDescription: String

    init {
        homeDescription = context.getString(R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description)
    }

    fun doSomeVoodoo() {
        val text : String = homeDescription
    }
}
```

alternatively, the above can be further simplified into:

```
class TestClass(context: Context) {
    private val homeDescription: String = context.getString(R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description)

    fun doSomeVoodoo() {
        val text : String = homeDescription
    }
}
```

### Decompiled Bytecode

And the decompiled java version of this feels a bit more acceptable than the other approaches and no reference to the context is held after construction:

```
public final class TestClass {
    private final String homeDescription;

    public final void doSomeVoodoo() {
        String text = this.homeDescription;
    }

    public TestClass(@NotNull Context context) {
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(context, "context");
        super();
        String var10001 = context.getString(2131296256);
        Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(var10001, "context.getString(R.stri…ion_bar_home_description)");
        this.homeDescription = var10001;
    }
}
```