# Kotlin - nonnull getter for a nullable field

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, kotlin, getter, non-nullable

I'm new with Kotlin and I try to rework a small Java project to this new language. I use mongodb in my project and I have a class, for example:

```
class PlayerEntity {

  constructor() {} //for mongodb to create an instance

  constructor(id: ObjectId, name: String) { //used in code
    this.id = id
    this.name = name
  }

  @org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id
  var id: ObjectId? = null

  var name: String? = null
}
```

I have to mark `id` field as nullable (`var id: ObjectId?`) because of empty constructor. When I try to access this field from another class I have to use non-null check: `thePlayer.id!!`. But the logic of my application is that `id` field is never null (mongo creates an instance of Player and immediately sets id field). And I don't want to make a non-null check everywhere.

I tried to make a non-null getter, but it does not compile:

```
var id: ObjectId? = null
    get(): ObjectId = id!!
```

I can also make some stub for id and use it in constructor, but this looks like a dirty hack:

```
val DUMMY_ID = new ObjectId("000000000000000000000000");
```

So is there a workaround to solve the issue?

Comment: put `lateinit` before your variable, it basically means, don't bother how but I ensure it will be initialized

Comment: Does [this similar problem in hibernate and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038177/kotlin-with-jpa-default-constructor-hell) help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally use a private var prefixed by `_` + public val in similiar situations.

```
class Example<out T> {
  private var _id: T? = null
  val id: T
    get() = _id!!
}
```

For your situation, it would look like this:

```
@org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id
private var _id: ObjectId? = null
val id: ObjectId
  get() = _id!!
```

---

Alternatively, declare your variable as `lateinit` like this (but note that this exposes the setter publicly):

```
@org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id
lateinit var id: ObjectId
```

Comment: `lateinit` is the correct thing to do in this case; no need to bother with a second property.

Comment: Thanks, `lateinit` is what I need

Comment: @yole Everybody his own, I have a personal dislike against `lateinit` for some reason.

Comment: "I personally use a private var prefixed by _ + public val in similiar situation".   What is the difference between this and a public var with a private setter? Is there one?

Comment: A getter/setter can't override it's parent var/val's type, so anybody consuming the getter would still have to non-null assert (`!!`) the return value.