# hibernate jpa projection with @Query

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-query

Most of the examples I've seen is using entityManager.createQuery or .createNativeQuery etc.

Is there a way to have something like the following working?

```
data class SummaryDto(val employeeName: String, val employerName: String)

@Query("select e.name as employeeName, emp.name as employerName " +
            "from Employer e " +
            "inner join Employee emp on emp.employer_id = e.id ", nativeQuery = true)
    fun findSummaries(): List<SummaryDto>
```

When I ran the above code

I got this error 
No converter found capable of converting from type 
`[org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [dto.SummaryDto]`

Can this be done with Kotlin or is there another way to get this to work with Hibernate JPA Annotation based?

Thanks
Tin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone that might run into the same problem. Change `SummaryDto` to an interface like this

`interface SummaryDto {
   val employeeName: String
   val employerName: String
}`

will work.

Comment: But why it works?